# What age is the kapoteh donned in Chabad circles?

Tags: minhag, clothing, chabad, age, social-convention

The kapoteh is a long black frock coat worn by some Lithuanian Jews and Chabad Chassidim. It is very similar to a bekishe.

I was wondering what age do most Chabad Chassidim start wearing the kapoteh. From bar mitzvah?

Comment: From the marriage,  chassidim of chabbad wear it on Shabbat and Yom Tov. The name is Sirtuk,  not kapete.  Kapete is in other chasiduyot and is in simili silk.

Comment: Is this Jews, or Judaism?

Comment: @kouty it is also called a kapote

Comment: @kouty - back up Menachem - I have also heard it called kapote in Chabad circles

Comment: ok.  may be that the name is a translation of coat or a mantle,  one in Russian language and one in Polish language

Comment: Kouty, le mot français «capote» et le mot yiddich «kapote» sont de la même origine. La capote Loubawitch s'appelle «redingote» en français. Je crois qu'un sirtouk est différent.

Comment: @Noach MiFrankfurt shkoyech. Up to now I totally forgot the word  "redingote". Yes you are right,  capote is in French a very thick cloth. But the fact is that very often when you find in a same language several etymologies for a same concept,  the language would maintain each of them but uses them for diverse subspecies. It is very frequent in English,  which has an enormous number of words due to the latin,  German and funicular origin for each word. Bravo pour votre français irréprochable.

Comment: @kouty, merci, mon יחוס maternal est français et j'adore l'écrire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the wedding day onward.

Discussed in the book Mazal Tov by Rabbi Nissan Dovid Dubov on page 64 
169. After the Kabbolas Ponim the chosson prepares for the chuppah in the following way.
170. The custom is that the chosson should wear a kittel. The Kittel is worn over a silk kapote but under a coat.

footnotes: the chosson doesn't wear the kittel the first yom kipur after after marriage. sefer haminhagim page 67. likkutei levi yitzchock igros kodesh p. 206 and also isru chag sukkos 5711 talks about the importance of wearing silk kappotes on shabbos and yontiff. from the Rebbe Rashab in sefer hamaamarim 5662 p. 231 and 247 talks about the importance of a silk garment on shabbos. also sefer hamamaarim 5673 page 328 (247), and sefer hamamaarim 5672 vol 2 p 872

From my personal observation though it seems like most chassanim put the kapote on before kabbolas ponim for the sake of convenience as that is when there are pictures being taken and the kittel and extra coat being put on right before the chuppah.

Another note: kapote, sirtuk, and bekishe are interchangeable names. There are many styles among these types of coats.

Comment: Todah rabbah lecha.

Comment: Isn't a kapote a frock coat? אם כן, the style referred to as a bekische (worn by most chassidim) is not a kapote, as it lacks the waisted construction of the former. Bekisches also aren't always black (especially by rebbeim)

Comment: I think those are implications based on how they are used but the words themselves mean the same thing. basically a long coat of some variety. In the same way the expression "suit" can refer to many styles of clothing

Comment: To clear up some confusion and incorrect assumptions: A frock coat (English), kapote (Yiddish), and sirtuk (Russian) are synonymous, and are all long black coats with a vent in the back, worn by married Lubavitch Chassidim on Shabbos and other holidays. A bekishe is worn by non-Lubavitch Chassidim (usually married, though not necessarily) on Shabbos and other holidays, (as well as by some Rebbes during the week). Bekishes do not have a slit in the back and could be a variety of colors.

Comment: A rekel is a long plain black coat w/o a slit in the back and is worn by non-Lubavitch Chassidim on weekdays and by some non-married non-Lubavitch Chassidim on Shabbos and other holidays.

Comment: @Dude I've never heard someone call it a bekishe in Chabad and am somewhat surprised that you have. Isn't a bekishe something different (maybe by a few inches in length, among other details?) Thanks